# Как закоммитить файл в уже существующий репозиторий?

Tags: git

В Sublime создаю новый файл в папке которая инициализирована git (git init). В git bash пишется "имя папки"(master), далаю git add, потом git commit и все здорово, но вот файла нет в репозитории. Создаю новый репозиторий и фаил появляется. По финалу на каждый день новый репозиторий. Что делать?

Comment: Помогла команда git push origin master

Comment: Я ж говорил ничего не исчезает из гита. Это машина времени. Он все помнит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы забыли про git push судя по приведенным действиям.

Могу порекомендовать почитать gitSCM

[Работа с удаленными репозиториями](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%B8)

[Запись и изменение](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: В вопросе, про удаленный репо ни слова

Comment: "но вот файла нет в репозитории" - мне показалось что именно о нем и речь

Comment: после `git push` файл должен быть на месте, а изменения уйти. Если до этого были `add` и `commit`. Тут другая проблема.